# Java JNI call taking very long time

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a program and deep down in the call hierarchy it calls:
sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.addNativeDropTarget();

In the source it has the following for

```
/**
* add the native peer's AwtDropTarget COM object
* @return reference to AwtDropTarget object
*/

native long addNativeDropTarget();
```

Is there somewhere I can look at the native code for the AwtDroptarget COM object to help figure out why it is taking so long to execute this on my machine (10 seconds clock and cpu time)? I think I might have a corrupt com object or DLL or something. Not sure.